# Animating CALayer ShadowOffset

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I want to animate the ShadowOffset of my layer with CATransaction. But the shadow appears
without animation:

[CATransaction begin];

```
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2]forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
logoIndex.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
[logoIndex.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(10, 30)];
[logoIndex.layer setShadowRadius:5];
```

[CATransaction commit];

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have the same issue. Found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you're using CATransaction? You may have a better time if you use direct property animation and add the animation to the layer.

I know this is several months old but figured I'd add my two cents in case you ever come back to it or someone else finds it.